# What font does Great Lakes Motorcoach use for their logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, logo

I'm looking to find this unique font in this logo:

[image: Great Lakes Motorcoach Logo]

I can't seem to find it anywhere since most of the letters are unique. I've tried uploading it to the first 5 links on Google for "find font by image" but nothing comes close.

Comment: The bounty yielded some interesting answers, but nothing that fit exactly. Matt and Sam's combined can get you pretty close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Advertisers Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hihretrofonts/advertisers-gothic/regular/glyphs.html) should be very close.

[image: Advertisers Gothic]

Comment: Stretch this vertically and use the `C` and `O` from Stage Serial or Revue BT, and that's the closest yet

Answer (score 4):

Its a modified font called [Revue BT Regular](http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/revuen.html).  All they did was add a stroke:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The G, T, and L look pretty close, but A, R, E look way off.

Comment: sorry I've searched all the sites I know and bounced the question to two boards.  It might be a software dedicated font.

Comment: Okay well thanks. What would you suggest I do to get font? Draw it in illustrator or photoshop?

Comment: are you trying to duplicate the logo exactly?  I would import it in Illustrator and reproduce the artwork.  I would assume this is for the buses, per the search about the company?

Answer (score 1):

font family is on stage serial medium

you can get that font here http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/softmaker/on-stage-serial/medium/

[image]

Comment: Similar style, but not the same font - particularly, A, K, R...

Answer (score 0):

It's an art nouveau / arts & crafts sort of thing with a hefty dose of 70s ITC. A little bit of Goudy, a little bit of Benguiat. The `A` is clearly an identifier but within that subset, the odd-shaped and historically inaccurate `O` is a good way to spot this design. Looks like two art nouveau `C`s grafted together.

I'm not aware of a perfect match but it's obviously not hand drawn. My guess is that it comes from one of the many half-baked freeware font sites. You might try digging  around [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) (not all bad, btw).